# Get detected face Pitch angle from Google ML Kit Mobile Vision API

Tags: react-native, machine-learning, computer-vision, face-detection, google-mlkit

I'm working on an app that needs to detect the face orientation, that is roll, yaw and pitch.

[image: Roll, Yaw, Pitch]

Since I'm using Expo (React Native) I hope I can stick with its [FaceDetector](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facedetector/) implementation which used [Google ML Kit's Mobile Vision API](https://developers.google.com/vision/face-detection-concepts). I'm fully aware this might not be the most efficient API for the task of solely retrieving face orientation information.

Sadly, the Google API only passes **Yaw** and **Roll** but not **Pitch**:

> The Euler X, Euler Y, and Euler Z angles characterize a face’s orientation as shown in Fig. 1. The Face API provides measurement of Euler Y and Euler Z (but not Euler X) for detected faces.

[image: Mobile Vision API Euler Angles]

Is there any way to calculate Pitch from the given Euler angles or at least approximate?

Additionally: What is the reason for that limitation?

Answer (score 0):

The [Face Detection API in ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection) (the successor to Google Mobile Vision) does report the EulerX for detected faces and maybe [this](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/8195/how-to-convert-euler-angles-to-quaternions-and-get-the-same-euler-angles-back-fr) should help clarify the conversion between Euler angles and Yaw/Roll/Pitch.